How to bound the first-order remainder in the Taylor expansion for $ f(A) = \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A)} $ perturbed by a matrix $ B $?
I am working with the matrix function $ f(A) = \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A)} $, where $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ is a positive definite matrix and $ \lambda_{\min}(A) $ is its smallest eigenvalue. I'm interested in finding a bound for the first-order remainder in the Taylor expansion of $ f $ around $ A $, perturbed by a matrix $ B $, i.e., $ f(A + \epsilon B) $.
More concretely, I have the first-order Taylor expansion of $ f $ around $ A $:
$f(A + \epsilon B) = f(A) + \epsilon \cdot Df(A)[B] + R_1(A, B, \epsilon)$
where $ Df(A)[B] = -\frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A)^2} v_{\min}^T B v_{\min} $, with $ v_{\min} $ being the eigenvector corresponding to $ \lambda_{\min}(A) $.
I want to bound the first-order remainder term $ R_1(A, B, \epsilon) $, which satisfies:
$R_1(A, B, \epsilon) = f(A + \epsilon B) - f(A) - \epsilon \cdot Df(A)[B]$
Does anyone have suggestions or references for bounding $ R_1(A, B, \epsilon) $ in terms of $ \epsilon $, $ B $, and possibly higher-order derivatives or properties of the eigenvalue function?
Thank you for your help!
